# Alert in JavaScript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, web, mobile

How can I display an alert with the results of a quiz? Now I obtain "plain text".

JavaScript:

```
// on submit, show results
submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
```

HTML5:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Edit: Here is the showResults function

```
  function showResults() {
// gather answer containers from our quiz
const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");
// keep track of user's answers
let numCorrect = 0;
// for each question...
myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
  // find selected answer
  const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
  const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
  const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;
  // if answer is correct
  if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
    // add to the number of correct answers
    numCorrect++;
    // color the answers green
    answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "seagreen";
  } else {
    // if answer is wrong or blank
    // color the answers red
    answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
  }
});
// show number of correct answers out of total
resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} correcta(s) de ${myQuestions.length}`;
```

}

Comment: You absolutely do not *need* jQuery, although it might make things easier in some cases. But we need to see your `showResults` function in order to help.

Comment: Did you consider having a hidden element and then just showing it with absolute positions? Why does it have to be an alert box?

Comment: I am using Onsen UI library if that helps.
I edited the question with the showResults function.

Comment: When you say `alert` in javascript people will think you're reffering to something like `alert("hello")` which will do the trick but it's not great because it is browser blocking and can't be styled. 

If you're looking for a pop up or modal then you can just use a `div` that is hidden until needed or you can use a library to make a modal easily.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. I will try to find a library. Thanks